# $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']='POST'; not working

Tags: php

It's not entering `if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')` so I tried
 `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']='POST'` still showing error

> Notice: Undefined index: qty in C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\new 1.php
>   on line 9
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Abyss Web
>   Server\htdocs\new 1.php on line 9

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\new 1.php on line 22

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    require('login_tools.php');
    load();
}
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']='POST';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        foreach($_POST['qty'] as $item_id => $item_qty){
            $id=(int)$item_id;
            $qty=(int)$item_qty;
            if($qty == 0){
                unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);
            }elseif($qty >0){
                $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity']=$qty;
            }
        }
        $total=0;$e=array();
        if(!empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
            require('connectDB.php');

            $q="SELECT * FROM shop WHERE item_id IN ";
            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id =>$value){
                $q.=$id.',';
            }
            $q=substr($e,0,-1); " )ORDER BY item_id ASC";
            $r=mysqli_query($dbc,$q);



        }else{
            $err[]="your cart is currently empty";
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']='POST';` why do this then check on the next line `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')`. doing this means that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` will always be `'POST'` regardless what it originally was and thus your if statement is completely useless

Comment: So you have a form somewhere that should be set to method POST and has an input named "qty" For whatever reason it's not populating $_POST['qty']  Try adding print_r($_POST); to see what the form is sending

Comment: This is horrible practice..... Set something to check that exact value makes it pointless.... Could you show your form that submits to this?